# Generating a program that generates a word pyramid pattern based on user input in Python

Tags: python

Requirements:

1. Ask the user to input a word.
2. Generate and print a pyramid pattern using the letters of the word.
3. Each level of the pyramid should display the letters of the word up to that level.
4. The word should be centered on each level of the pyramid.

Additional requirements:

1. Implement a function to validate the input and ensure it's a valid word.
2. Allow the user to choose the direction of the pyramid (upwards or downwards).
3. Enhance the program to handle phrases instead of single words.

Expected Output:
if word level is up:

```
            S    
           S u   
          S u n  
         S u n i 
        S u n i l
```

if word level is Down:

```
            S u n i l
             S u n i 
              S u n  
               S u   
                S
```

Tried code:

```py
import string

def validate_word(word):
    if not word.isalpha():
        return False
    if not word.isascii():
        return False
    if len(word) < 3:
        return False
    return True

def get_word_from_user():
    while True:
        word = input("Enter a word: ").strip()
        if validate_word(word):
            return word
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid word.")

def get_pyramid_direction():
    while True:
        direction = input("Choose the direction of the pyramid (up/down): ").strip().lower()
        if direction in ['up', 'down']:
            return direction
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter 'up' or 'down'.")

def print_pyramid(word, direction):
    levels = len(word)
    for i in range(levels):
        if direction == 'up':
            print(' ' * (levels - i - 1) + ' ' + word[:i+1].center(2*i+1) + ' ' * (levels - i - 1))
        else:
            print(' ' * i + word[:i+1].center(2*i+1) + ' ' * i)

def main():
    word = get_word_from_user()
    direction = get_pyramid_direction()
    print_pyramid(word, direction)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code is giving out following output:

for up:

```
  R     
  Ra    
 Raj    
 Raje   
Rajes   
Rajesh
```

for down:

```
r
  ra 
    raj   
     raje    
      rajes      
        rajesh
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].  See also the [Stack Overflow homework FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be overcomplicating the solution. IMO you do not need to add trailing whitespace. Also, if you replace `word[:i+1].center(2*i+1)` with `' '.join(word[:i+1]))`, you get the correct output for the UP case, but not the DOWN case. To make the DOWN case work correctly, you need to iterate over levels in reverse.

Here's how I would personally solve the problem:

```
def make_pyramid(S, direction='up'):
    parts = []
    r = range(1, len(S)+1) if direction == 'up' else range(len(S), 0, -1)
    for i in r:
        parts.append(' ' * (len(S) - i) + ' '.join(S[:i]))
    
    return '\n'.join(parts)

print(make_pyramid('Sunil was here'))
print(make_pyramid('Sunil was here', direction='down'))
```

```
             S
            S u
           S u n
          S u n i
         S u n i l
        S u n i l  
       S u n i l   w
      S u n i l   w a
     S u n i l   w a s
    S u n i l   w a s  
   S u n i l   w a s   h
  S u n i l   w a s   h e
 S u n i l   w a s   h e r
S u n i l   w a s   h e r e
S u n i l   w a s   h e r e
 S u n i l   w a s   h e r
  S u n i l   w a s   h e
   S u n i l   w a s   h
    S u n i l   w a s  
     S u n i l   w a s
      S u n i l   w a
       S u n i l   w
        S u n i l  
         S u n i l
          S u n i
           S u n
            S u
             S
```

As a side note, I prefer my functions don't have side effects (such as printing stuff out), so I return the string and have the caller print it instead.